# How to update image and delete image from two tables?

Tags: php, laravel, crud, updates

I have two tables `image_rekap` and `rekaps` how to update image and delete image.

Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    if($request->has('search')) {
        $data = rekap::where('customer', 'LIKE', '%' .$request->search. '%')->paginate(5);
    } else {
        $data = rekap::paginate(5);
    }
    return view('rekap')->with([
            'data' => $data,
    ]);
}
public function insert_rekap(Request $request){
    // dd($request->all());
    $data = $request->validate([
        'customer'=>'required',
        'vessel'=>'required',
        'scopejob'=>'required',
        'pergantian_sparepart'=>'required',
        'teknisi'=>'required',
        'tahun'=>'required',
        'keterangan'=>'required'
    ]);
    $new_data= rekap::create($data);
    if($request->has('images')){
        foreach($request->file('images')as $image){
            $imageName = $data['customer'].'-image-'.time().rand(1,1000).'.'.$image->extension();
            $image->move(public_path('data_images'),$imageName);
            Image_rekap::create([
                'rekap_id'=>$new_data->id,
                'image'=>$imageName
            ]);
        }
    }
    return redirect()->route('rekap')->with('success','Data Berhasil Ditambahkan');
}

public function images($id){
    $data = rekap::find($id);
    if(!$data) abort(404);
    $images = $data->images;
    return view ('image_rekap',compact('data','images'));
}
public function update_rekap(Request $request,$id){
    $data = rekap::find($id);
    $data->update($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('rekap')->with('success','Data Berhasil di Update');
}

public function delete_rekap($id){
    $data = rekap::find($id);
    $data->delete();
    return redirect()->route('rekap')->with('success','Data berhasil dihapus');
}
```

and I have 2 model classes:

Model `rekap`:

```
class rekap extends Model {
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function images() {
        return $this->hasMany(Image_rekap::class);
    }
}
```

Model class `image_rekap`:

```
class Image_rekap extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

Comment: Do you want to delete a specific image or images for a specific `rekap` item?  What do you mean by multiple tables? Your images are storing in only one table

Comment: i want to delete and update a spesific image, because in the html table I made one table @MuhammadShareyar

Comment: If you want to delete an image on an image update then you can just simply send that record `id` on your update request and on just update the record image path.

Comment: show the code how to update @MuhammadShareyar